# jQuery UI AutoComplete - How to implement progress-indicator?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, progress-indicator

If the question title wasn't clear enough:

I am using the jQuery AutoComplete plugin (part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) 1.8.5)

I would have thought the supplied CSS/images would include an ajax-like progress image?

If not, what's the easiest way to create one?

This is my autocomplete code:

```
$('#query').autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
         url: "/Search/FindLocations",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         data:
         {
            searchText: request.term
         },
         success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
               return { name: item.name, value: item.name }
            }))
         }),
   select: function (event, ui) {
      // snip... (this is where i display stuff about what they clicked).
   }});
```

Where should i hide/show an image in the above code?

Obviously after the code in "select", i could hide an image, but where can i "show" the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#query').autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
      //i would show the image here, before starting your ajax request
      $("#theImage").show();
      $.ajax({
         url: "/Search/FindLocations",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         data:
         {
            searchText: request.term
         },
         success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
               return { name: item.name, value: item.name }
            }))
         }),
   select: function (event, ui) {
      // snip... (this is where i display stuff about what they clicked).
   }});
```

Comment: So where is the image hidden again?  Shouldn't this occur in a `$.ajax({complete: ....})` or `$.ajax(...).always(...)`?

Comment: Hey, I simply copied his code and added two lines to demonstrate showing an image before the ajax request begins. He said: "Obviously after the code in 'select', i could hide an image, but where can i 'show' the image?". I assumed he was hiding the image in the select callback and did not add any code to hide an image.